# How to add header in my Reactjs app as per authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I have four different header components in my whole ReactJs app.

HeaderA : Users without authentication,
HeaderB : first time logged in user
HeaderC : Authenticated users who are not first time users.
HeaderD : Authenticated users and pointing to specific urls.

I have tried this but doesn't seems to be working. Please suggest any better method.

```
{!authenticated && (<HeaderA></HeaderA>)}
{authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="true" && (<HeaderB/>)}
{authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="false" && pathname==="/" && (<HeaderC/>)}
{authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="false" && pathname!=="/specificRoute" && pathname!=="/" && (<HeaderD/>)}
```

Comment: `ftu === "true"` don't do this, use booleans, not strings

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional logic is blocking some of the elements to be rendered, as `if(ftu && ftu === false)` never can be true because the first ftu is expected to be truthy.

Unless that is the reason why you use strings instead of bools to keep track. But then it wouldn't make sense to check for ftu, because it will always be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) if it contains either `true` or `false`. Only empty strings `""` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Instead, I would write the logic as follows:

```
const MyComponent = ({authenticated, ftu, pathname}) => {

   const getHeader = () => {
      if(!authenticated) return <HeaderA />
      if(authenticated && ftu) return <HeaderB />
      if(authenticated && !ftu && pathname==="/specificRoute") return <HeaderD />
      if(authenticated && !ftu) return <HeaderC />
      return null; // Maybe return HeaderC here instead.
   }

   return (
      <div>
         {getHeader()}
         <OtherComponent />
         <ThirdComponent />
      </div>
   )
}
```

The reason for using a function is to ensure only one header is returned. If you do the if logic within the render area, you might risk two (or more) being returned if conditions are true. Also, i put C below D, because C would be true if D is true, but D can be false while C is still true.

I imagine that C would be your default Header, so maybe it could just be returned instead of null if none of the above conditions are met?

Answer (score 0):

```
{!authenticated ?(<HeaderA></HeaderA>):
authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="true" ? (<HeaderB/>):
authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="false" && pathname==="/" ? (<HeaderC/>):
authenticated &&  ftu && ftu==="false" && pathname!=="/specificRoute" && pathname!=="/" ? (<HeaderD/>):null}
```